# Cannot see my HTTP trigger function in azure function app deployed by azure Devops ci cd pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-functions, azure-yaml-pipelines

Developed one azure Devops yaml pipeline to publish my azure function in the azure function app, even it is running fine but still even after the push I cannot see my azure function gets deployed in Azure yaml pipeline. However I can see in the azure function app "deployment center" I can see my commit ids but under the overview tab nothings is there.

Below is the YAML pipeline:

```
trigger: none

pool:
 name: test
stages:
- stage: deploy_function_app
  jobs:
    - deployment: FunctionAppDeployment
      displayName: 'Function App Deployment'
      environment: dev
      strategy:
        runOnce:
          deploy:
            steps:
              - checkout: self
                clean: true

              - task: ArchiveFiles@2
                displayName: 'Create project zip'
                inputs:
                  rootFolderOrFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/src'
                  includeRootFolder: false
                  archiveType: 'zip'
                  archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/functionapp.zip'
                  replaceExistingArchive: true

              - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
                displayName: 'Publish zip artifact'
                inputs:
                  targetPath: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/functionapp.zip'
                  publishLocation: 'pipeline'
      
              - task: AzureFunctionApp@1
                displayName: 'Deploy Function App'
                inputs:
                  azureSubscription: 'connection'
                  appType: 'functionapp'
                  appName: 'myfunctionsharat'
                  package: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/functionapp.zip'
                  deploymentMethod: 'zipDeploy'
```

Comment: What language is your function is? I think you may be missing a package installation/building step but I am not sure if that is required for all languages.

Comment: @KonTheCat first of all thanks for your reply, it's a typescript project. I used a visual studio code to create a sample function for the testing. Then pushed it to azure repo.

Comment: This is my code repo: https://github.com/sharatbhaskar1988/azure-function-test/blob/main/src/functions/developerhttpfunction.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have checked the Github Repo sample and reproduced the same issue.

You can refer to the following steps to modify your project and Pipeline:

For the Repo Project, you need to add the **Function.json** file to the path: **src/functions**

Function.json sample:

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "anonymous",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req",
      "methods": [
        "get",
        "post"
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "res"
    }
  ],
  "scriptFile": "../dist/src/functions/developerhttpfunction.js"
}
```

File path:

[image]

For the Azure DevOps Pipeline, you need to **Build** the TS project first, then you can deploy the generated package to Azure Function.

Here is an example:

```
stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build stage
  jobs:
  - job: Build
    displayName: Build
    pool:
      name: test

    steps:
    - task: NodeTool@0
      inputs:
        versionSpec: '18.x'
      displayName: 'Install Node.js'


    - script: |
        npm install
     
  
      displayName: 'Prepare binaries'
    - script: |

        npm run build
  
      displayName: 'Build Project'

    - task: ArchiveFiles@2
      displayName: 'Archive files'
      inputs:
        rootFolderOrFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
        includeRootFolder: false
        archiveType: zip
        archiveFile: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
        replaceExistingArchive: true

    - upload: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
      artifact: drop

- stage: Deploy
  displayName: Deploy stage
  dependsOn: Build
  condition: succeeded()
  jobs:
  - deployment: Deploy
    displayName: Deploy
    environment: test
    pool:
      name: test
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - task: AzureFunctionApp@1
            displayName: 'Azure Functions App Deploy: my-function-app-name'
            inputs:
              azureSubscription: 'xxx'
              appType: 'functionApp'
              appName: 'xxx'
              package: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
              deploymentMethod: 'auto'
```

**Result:**

[image]

Refer to this doc: [Azure Functions triggers and bindings concepts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-triggers-bindings?tabs=isolated-process%2Cpython-v2&pivots=programming-language-csharp)

Comment: thank you so much, it worked. Thanks a lot once again.